# jQuery works in console not in script 'syntax error, unexpected h4'

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'h4' (T_STRING) in //// on line 76

The line of code I am using is this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('h4:contains("Billing Details")').text("Destination Details").addClass("destinationheading")
})
```

If I remove it from the script and enter it manually into the console it works fine. What's causing this? If it makes any difference this is in wordpress' functions file.

The function is inside of a php function which is echoing out the javascript.

The PHP function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){


    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Origin First Name').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Origin First Name', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<script>jQuery(function(){ jQuery('h4:contains("Billing Details")').text("Destination Details").addClass("destinationheading") }) </script>';

}
```

Comment: No, it's inside a php function which is echoing out the javascript.

Comment: Other jquery calls are working inside of it. Just this one is not.

Comment: post the php function as well

Comment: in the echo there is a quote between start quote and end quote is this valid? probably escape char '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do triple-nested quotes - first single-quotes in PHP, then single&double in JS. Because of this, you end PHP string. Try escaping quotes characters with `\'`'s and `\"`'s.

Your script is at the moment interpreted like this:

```
echo '...jQuery(' h4:contains("Billing Details") ').text(...)';
```

so PHP treats `h4:contains("Billing Details")` as it's own code. Escape characters instead - use this line:

```
echo "<script>jQuery(function(){ jQuery('h4:contains(\"Billing Details\")').text(\"Destination Details\").addClass(\"destinationheading\") }) </script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Taught me something interesting today.

Answer (score 1):

see comments use escape for the \

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){

```
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){ jQuery(\'h4:contains("Billing Details")\').text("Destination Details").addClass("destinationheading") }) </script>';
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Quite a messy thing to do. Learned something new today :)